# Since slow hard drive is the item that makes a notebook slow, will SSD completely turn the table on speed?

Tags: ssd, laptop

By using a top-notched SSD (solid state drive), can a notebook feel faster than a desktop computer?

Comment: I don't know where you're getting this idea that notebooks are slower than desktops. My laptop *smokes* my desktop.

Comment: This is very subjective... perhaps you should be more specific about what you're comparing.

Answer (score 1):

You would notice a performance difference in the laptop.

However other factors such as processor speed, amount of memory, motherboard will determine how much a difference it will make.

A slow processor, low memory and low-end motherboard etc the difference will be less obvious.

My laptop is far faster than my desktop even though it has a slower hard drive (5,400 RPM compared to the desktops 7,200 RPM).

It depends on what the spec is but having a SSD will improve the laptop speed and reliability if it's being bashed about a bit.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows 7 ensure the hard drive is the slowest component on your system by comparing the 5 results from the Windows Experience Index.

If your hard drive is the slowest component then it might be worth upgrading the hard drive.

I upgraded from a 5400 rpm to a 7200 rpm drive on my laptop and it only increased the score by 0.3